# Firebase database not working properly in android after running in "APK from App bundle"

Tags: android, firebase, proguard, release

Normal Apk runs perfectly fine but when I select "Apk from app bundle". The app crashed when I tried to log in. When I reopen the app it signs me in but without creating a necessary node in firebase's real-time database.

When I try to "sign in with google" in my project it brings me back to login page but somehow it adds my email address in firebase auth and creates a node in fireabse relatime database

it only logs this error

> 2022-07-28 15:11:48.505 4713-4713/com.example.simplemoneytracking A/libc: fdsan: attempted to close file descriptor 98, expected to be unowned, actually owned by FILE* 0x75f14a80c0
>
> 2022-07-28 15:11:48.505 4713-4713/com.example.simplemoneytracking A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE) in tid 4713 (lemoneytracking), pid 4713 (lemoneytracking)

When I remove the app from the background and clear the cache and reopen the app it loads the app with my gmail photo and name but it does not create a necessary node in the database and doesn't allow me to create one from the app.
But I can write other data to database (like adding expenses and other stuff)

Things I have tried to make firebase work in release
-> All 3 SHA-1 keys were added to the firebase project setting and .json file is up to date
-> configured my proGuard.pro file as below
-> also tried minifyEnabled false but nothing happend

My ProGuard File

```
-keepattributes Signature
-keepclassmembers class com.example.mypackage.model.** {
  *;
}
-keep class com.firebase.** { *; }
```

App level build.gradle

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled true
            multiDexEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release

        }
```

Comment: When an app crashes, it writes an error message and stack trace to its logcat. Please find those, and add them to your question by clicking the `edit` link under it. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond using @.

Comment: @AlexMamo thank you so much for showing interest I have updated the post with necessary errors and added for information

Comment: That error message looks unfamiliar to me, but it's also quite void of most information. Is there really no stack trace showing?

Answer (score 0):

Also getting same issue but i tried by removing it  debuggable false minifyEnabled true multiDexEnabled true  then it only work or you can mention this in proguard rule

```
-dontshrink
-dontobfuscate
-dontoptimize
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33503504)